# MySQL - Iterate through a column, change value if condition is met

Tags: mysql

I am looking to change the values inside the table users - column experience. Aiming at changing the values to 21 if a value is > 20. What I am looking for is a loop that would iterate through the entire table's column using the following logic (sorry, illustrating the best I can):

```
var column = users.experience
for (var i = 0, l = column.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (users.experience > 20) {
       users.experience = 21; 
    }
}
```

Users have different levels of experience, ranging from 0 to 40. The search filter has changed an I am trying to adapt the existing table to it. Searched through similar topics, but did not find any direct answer to the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a mysql `UPDATE` query having `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: Mmm, like this?

UPDATE users
 SET experience = CASE WHEN experience > 20 THEN '21' END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is update the `experience` field to 21 for all records where the `experience` field is currently > 20 (21, 22, 23, ..., 40), you just need a simple UPDATE query---no looping required:

```
update users set experience = 21 where experience > 20
```

This is SQL, where you need to think in terms of recordsets, not in terms of looping familiar to imperative programming. Of course, SQL does offer looping in forms of [cursors](https://www.essentialsql.com/database-cursor/), but that doesn't seem to be necessary in your case.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was the lack of knowledge about declarative and iterative languages, hence was looking for a loop.